# AWS shield vs AWS macie vs inspector query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am preparing for AWS certified practitioner exam. Was going though the security services Amazon shield, Amazon macie and Amazon inspector.
Shield gives protection against DDoS, Macie analyses data using machine learning and AWS inspector finds security vulnerabilities for EC2 instances.

My question is if inspector can be replaced for macie and macie for shield ?

Or they provide different services all together and I need to utilise all three for security in AWS?

Sounds a bit stupid but need to resolve this

Comment: You might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/AWSCertifications/

Answer (score 0):

As I see it No

Inspector is more of a vulnerability management tool
Macie currently monitors your s3 buckets and identifies data stored within the buckets that match your desired data protection scans
Shield, this give not only DDOS protection but also WAS to your web applications